# How to take snapshot of RTSP streaming using LibVLC for Android

Tags: android, snapshot, libvlc, textureview

I am using libVLC in an Android application for RTSP streaming. Since video is loaded over [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) in libVLC, we cannot take snapshot directly.

So how to support snapshot functionality with LibVLC for Android?

One solution would be by loading the video over [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). We can use getBitmap function to get the snapshot of currently playing video using the function [getBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap()). 
How to add support for textureView in libVLC?

I have gone through the source code VLC. I found this file [snapshot.c](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/snapshot_8c.html). Is it possible to use this to enable snapshot functionality in Android?

Comment: use this link : https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=122463

Comment: @Deepak that was answered by OP itself https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=122463#p413301

Answer (score 1):

libVLC 2.1.12 supports using a TextureView, so you can use getBitmap().